# How can I avoid hard-coding multiple elements into my Django model?

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow, so thank you in advance for your insight. This is a question about Django 3.0 (so Python 3.6+).

**Use case:**

Let's say I've successfully parsed through the [Code of Federal Regulations](https://www.govinfo.gov/bulkdata/ECFR/title-22) and I've determined that each regulation has three parts - the citation, the subject, and the regulation itself. I can parse these into a nested dictionary at need (or XML, or CSV, or any format really).

The dictionary is something like this like this:

```
{ 
  'citation 1' : {'Subject of Regulation 1' : 'Text of regulation'} 
  'citation 2' : {'Subject of Regulation 2 : 'More regulatory text'}

}
```

There's hundreds of regulations and citations. I don't want to hard-code these regulations into my model, so I want to store them in a dictionary and call them to my model.

Let's also assume I have a complex business that needs to comply with many of these regulations, so I have to figure out whether each regulation is **applicable** and how I'm going to implement it.

So this is my models.py

```
class CFR(models.Model):
    citation = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    regulation_text = models.TextField()
    applicable = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    implementation = models.TextField()
```

The model contains fields for applicability and implementation.

My forms.py. Yes I know I shouldn't use `__all__`.

```
class RegulationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = CFR
        fields = ('__all__')
```

and my views.py

```
class ApplicabilityView(CreateView):
    model = CFR
    template_name = "template.html"
    form_class = RegulationForm
```

I'd like to use the model to:

1. Iterate through each regulation in the dictionary.
2. Render a form containing all of the regulations in the dictionary
3. Append the two fields from the model to each regulation the form ( the **applicable** and **implementation** fields).
4. Have one save button at the end of the form.

I was hoping to pass the dictionary of the regulations into the queryset using `def get_initial`, but I can't seem to figure that out. Passing a dictionary would allow me to re-use the code with any part of the CFR so long as I can work out how to make a dictionary.

The alternative is hard-coding **all** the regulations into my `models.py` - and I'd rather find a solution that is more flexible.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're asking how to have a single form to update several (all?) instances of a single model?

Comment: @Chris I think so, if I"m interpreting your question right. I want the model and the form to be able to handle any number of regulations.

Answer (score 0):

Some options may be:

1. Postgres specific json field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField
2. Maria/MySQL JSON Field https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html
3. django-annoying  package json field https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying#jsonfield
4. Use NoSQL https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This comment finally nudged me to moving to Postgres. I will have to read the docs about the JSONField further before I can figure out if it is the solution I need.